# Proof Application of Jensen's Inequality

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Let $(X_1,...,X_n)$ be a random sample S from a population with a finite variance.  I want to prove, using Jensen's inequality that $ES \leq \sigma$.  I'm not so sure but I feel like something's missing from allowing me to jump straight into Jensen's Inequality. If there isn't, I guess I really don't know it that well and could use some help.  Can someone advise me on how to apply it?